# Weird behaviour in angular js when increment

Tags: angularjs

Consider this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/iEU0gZQTtj22Eo2Ncr92?p=preview

```
//controller
    $scope.count =0; 
     $scope.add = function(){
       $scope.count++;
     };
```

All i want to achieve is this:

Whenever my html encounter the $scope.add function, increment by one.

For some reason it increments by 10, any reason why?

Comment: You actually have an infinite digest issue, and its just stopping at 10 because that's the maximum number of digests that angular will allow.

Comment: Simply don't call scope methods directly in a view expression. Only do this as a response to some event being triggered (e.g. button click etc.)

Comment: If i really need incrementing something this way, no possible way at all?

Comment: You better explain what the purpose of this would be. Sounds to me like an [XyProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: I want to do something like $index, only on certain ng-repeat elements, meaning some will increment, and some won't...

Comment: Then write a filter. Or prepare your data inside the controller and use `$watch` to check for underlying changes. Also I would recommend you update your question to include the real problem with some some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing count outside the scope and calling add twice. I have defined count inside the scope and got the result.
have a look at this

```
[1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/3NQye0axRwdpsl2kf4lq?p=preview
```

Yeah its a weird behavior but you can achieve this with firing events like on click. or else ng-init and call your function. have a look. I dont know this will do your work or not still have look. thanks.
                 [updated link](http://plnkr.co/edit/rsBF29A09yyfUFP5MfPj?p=preview)

Comment: Where is the plunker?

Comment: check out sorry i dont included link first time. did you got it now?

Comment: No it's not what i need, i want to increment everytime in the index i call add(), what you do here is reset to 1 everytime...

Answer (score -1):

My sample is not a good solution but It works. Your problem is because of Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop.You can check detail in [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig).

But if you really want to ,please check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/meazuri/oqznnjrd/1/.
This is controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[],function($rootScopeProvider) {
  $rootScopeProvider.digestTtl(0);
});
function MyCtrl($scope) {


    $scope.myInit = function(){
         $rootScopeProvider.digestTtl(1);
    }
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.count =0;
    $scope.added = function(){   
        $scope.count += 1;
    }
}
```

This is html file

```
   <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">


            {{count}}
            {{added()}}
            {{count}}
            {{added()}}
            {{count}}
    </div>
```

I created by setting the number of $digest iterations to 0.

digestTtl(limit);
Sets the number of $digest iterations the scope should attempt to execute before giving up and assuming that the model is unstable.

The current default is 10 iterations.

Comment: I'm sorry I have to downvote this, because it's such bad practice, that nobody coming here should think it's a good idea to simply disable the digest limit. If the OT would clarify the problem there is probably a much better way to handle this.

Comment: I also really do not think that is a good solution.But I couldn't find a way to solve that kind of problem.

Comment: To be honest, if the OT issn't actively helping by answering questions asked regarding his/her question. Then it's sometimes better to not answer at all.